# delicate way to get a list of years and month between two given dates

Tags: php, date

i want to get a list of years and month between two given date

here is my code

```
    function yearMonth($start_date, $end_date)  
    {  

        $years = array();
        $base  = 0 ;
        while(($start_date) < $end_date)
        {

                $y           = date('Y' , $start_date);
                // if its the original start_time check the month from 
                //current date else get the first day and month in that year
                $base        = ($base == 0 )  ? $start_date : strtotime("{$y}-1-1"); 

                for($i = 1 ; $i <= 12 ; $i++ )
                {
                   if($base > $end_date)
                   break;
                   $years[date("Y", $start_date)][] = date("F" , $base); 
                   $base += 2629743.83;

                }

               $base += $start_date += 31556926 ;


        }
        return $years;

    }  

    $list  =  yearMonth(strtotime("2010-11-8") , strtotime("2012-11-11") );  
    var_dump($list);
```

so here is the problem

```
$base     = ($base == 0 )  ? $start_date : strtotime("{$y}-1-1");
```

in here i check if `start_date` is the original which i passed to the function 
if it is i set the base for finding the months in that year  equal to start_date 
and if it's not the original i set the base equal to the first month of that year

now we get to my problem

```
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 12 ; $i++ )
```

in here i assume there is 12 month in that year but if it is the original start_date it could be less

how can i calculate the remaining month in a given dates year?

another problem is here

```
            for($i = 1 ; $i <= 12 ; $i++ )
            {
                   if($base > $end_date)
                   break;
                   $years[date("Y", $start_date)][] = date("F" , $base); 
                   $base += 2629743.83;

            }
```

so i'm thinking each month has 2629743.83 seconds but it's not very accurate becuz of the leap year

is there any cleaner way to do this ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you give us some sample input and intended output?

Comment: "_but it's not very accurate becuz of the leap year_" or, you know, how the months are different lengths.

Comment: @Eric how can i calculate the remaining month of year in a given date year ? and if there is a more accurate way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two solutions, either altering your existing code or by using PHP's in-built DateTime classes.

You want to fix two things in your code:

- Listing only the remaining months of the starting year - you can do this by adding a check that your `$base` date is in the year you are outputting.
- Get the correct months in each years array - we can do this by incrementing the `$base` by the correct number of days for each month. We can get the number of days in the month using `date('t')`.

```php
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 12 ; $i++ )
{
   if($base > $end_date)
   break;
   $base_year = date('Y', $base);
   if ($base_year == $y) {
    $years[date("Y", $start_date)][] = date("F" , $base); 
    $base += 60*60*24*date('t', strtotime($base_year.'-'.$i."-1")); 
   }
}
```

Alternatively, you can simplify your code by using the DateTime objects. This example is based on some of the code in the comments to [DatePeriod](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php).

Note: the function's arguments don't need the dates parsed with `strtotime`.

```
function yearMonth($start_date, $end_date) 
{

    $begin = new DateTime( $start_date );
    $end = new DateTime( $end_date);
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1M'); // 1 month interval

    $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

    foreach ( $period as $dt )
        $years[$dt->format( "Y" )][] = $dt->format( "F" );

    return $years;

}

$list  =  yearMonth("2010-11-8", "2012-11-11");  
var_dump($list);
```

Comment: thank you DateTime objects seems really neat i'm going to use this one.